# Android orange border apears on app Icon

Tags: android, icons

I have developed an app, and have included the `hdpi`, `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi` icons with size 72, 96 and 144 respectively but on some device an orange border appears is visible around the icon as the icon is still smaller ?

What is reason and how to correct it ?

Thanks.

Comment: why not try posting your XML layout and graphics. Mighty hard to debug from just a description

Comment: Its the app icon that appears this way ? What xml do you need for that ?

Comment: Does it had to do anything with xml ? If yes, then which one ?